# SQL Server query get count of X on 15th of each month

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to create an SQL query that gets the count of employees that were employed as of the 15th of each month of the last 5 years.

This query gets me a single month:

```
SELECT
    SUM(X.CountOfEmployees)
FROM (SELECT
    COUNT(CNCEmployeeID) AS CountOfEmployees
FROM dbo.CNCEmployees
GROUP BY CNCEmployeeStartDate,
         CNCEmployeeDateLeft
HAVING (CNCEmployeeStartDate < CONVERT(datetime, '2016-07-15 00:00:00', 102))
AND ((CNCEmployeeDateLeft > CONVERT(datetime, '2016-07-15 00:00:00', 102))
OR (CNCEmployeeDateLeft IS NULL))) AS X
```

What I am looking for would output:

```
Jan 2016 - 32
Feb 2016 - 33
Mar 2016 - 33
```

etc. for each month that we have data.

I know how to create a Query and at least make it quick to change the dates by hand by adding a variable and changing that over and over (in fact I will probably do that to get the report done today for the last 12 months).  I believe that there is a better way to do this in one step without the need to manually go through each month.

Comment: I think you'll want a second table with your target dates (the 15th of each month going back 5 years) so you can do a `full outer join` with your employees table.

Comment: Can you provide more info about what columns you have in the CNCEmployees table?

Comment: Beth --  I'll try that real quick -- thanks     Abner -- the other columns are standard employee type fields -- firstName, lastName, etc.  This table is simple a list of employees with start and end dates of their employement.

Comment: Just a thought, I can see this query getting complex. Can you move the logic outside the query (are you running it from code?). If your stuck with a single query, then the best way to get help here is to also provide SQL statements to create your table and seed with dummy data. This way, it is clear to the reader what they have to work with - and much easier for them to get started. Your much more likely to get an answer that way. Heck, I might even step up to the challenge.

Comment: I don't have any outside program running this.  It will be a monthly report emailed to management directly from the SQL server.  I can create a sample data table if I don't get an answer right away, Beth and Gordon have promising thoughts, so I am exploring those first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method generates for the 60 months and use that in the `join`:

```
with dates as (
      select cast(dateadd(day, 16 - day(getdate()), getdate()) as date) as thedate, 1 as num
      union all
      select dateadd(month, -1, thedate), num + 1
      from dates
      where num <= 60
     )
select d.thedate, count(e.CNCEmployeeStartDate)
from dates d left join
     dbo.CNCEmployees e
     on e.CNCEmployeeStartDate <= d.thedate and
        (e.CNCEmployeeDateLeft >= d.thedate or e.CNCEmployeeDateLeft is null)
group by d.thedate;
```

This is not the most efficient method, but if you have a few hundred or thousand employees it should be fine in terms of performance.

Comment: This looks promising, I am getting an error on the DateAdd(Cast ......  -- invalid parameter.  I will look into it as well, once I wrap my head around what is happening here.

Comment: dateadd(getdate(), 16 - day(getdate()), getdate()) as date) should be dateadd(m, 16 - day(getdate()), getdate()) as date) in order to work -- the first getdate() is incorrect.  The solution works though -- thanks.